# What's the safe route to include a Google Drive and a database on a public project?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm working on a Python project which code will be public on GitHub but the tool is connected to a Google Drive folder and an AWS database.

How should I include them safely in the tool?

As of now, for the drive I used a IAM account and I included in the project the service account JSON file. Then I used the Google libraries to build the resource.
For the database I used `mysql-connector` and put the database info (user, pw, endpoint, ...) as explicit variables.

I'm not really concerned about data protection since the data is public itself but when I tried to make the project public I got a notice for "Google Cloud Keys exposed" and same for OAauth.

How should I implement the code to make it safe?

Comment: _Don't_ include the credentials in the source code - provide them via environment variables. Use e.g. https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ to make managing your local env easier across multiple projects.

Comment: Alternatively put them into a config.yaml or a similar file that you exclude from source control using `.gitignore`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The thing is that I want the user to still be able to connect to the database and the drive folder so in the end wouldn't I still need to share the .env (or .yaml) file?